# Stack exchange content copied to helptouser.com

Tags: discussion

I was going through the list of "unanswered questions" looking for any that were worth answering.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/sprinter-universal-bike caught my eye because there were some keywords that looked like good search-engine terms.

The top google match is SE Bicycles, but the second is: http://www.helptouser.com/bicycles/23627-sprinter-universal-bike.html

Its word for word the same question, and they've appeared to have mined Stackexchange around 2015 July 10, whereas the original question was asked a year earlier on 2014 July 15.

This helptouser.com site has pinched all the stackexchange categories, and their footer claims copyright over the content.  No attribution to Stack Exchange or the SE users has been given - its blatant plagiarism.

> Copyright © 2015 Help To User All Rights Reserved. Mobile 51.La
>   网站流量统计系统

**Question:** what can be done about it?

Given this is not just a SE Bicycles thing, should I raise the same question on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ ?

EDIT: 
I reported this at https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact but I don't know what can be done about it.

There is a google report form at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14CP_1An9rWKjJ8ZXqxg1gwVt44qTDxHPnXEa_ZGbHBc/viewform?formkey=dGM4TXhIOFd3c1hZR2NHUDN1NmllU0E6MQ&ndplr=1   but this is for when the scraper's page ranking puts their link above stackexchange link in the google results page.

Comment: Any updates????

Comment: They're still actively skimming the content - a recent question about http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35698/how-do-you-know-if-your-local-bike-club-is-worth-paying-for  is listed on their site.  There is no attribution visible on their site as to where the content comes from.  Apparently SE has a department who deal with this stuff, I suspect it will end up with legal action somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should put this question on Meta.SE. I don't think asking it on Bicycles.SE is useful, since its more something that needs to be dealt with by StackExchange administrative staff.

If you go to the bottom of the stackexchange page and click contact us, theres an option for SE content being reproduced without attribution, so you should fill that forum out as well.

Comment: @Criggie Did you do as Batman suggests, and what was the response?